# Postgres update view with NOT NULL constraints on its base table

Tags: postgresql, view, constraints, sql-insert, notnull

#PostgreSQL 10.22

Lets say I have a table and a view of it such as in:

```
CREATE TABLE item
(
    id integer Not Null,
    name varchar(50) Not Null
);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_items AS(
SELECT i.id 
FROM item i
)
WITH CHECK OPTION
```

When I try to insert a tuple to **all_items** view I get an error because of the 'Not Null' constraint on the base table. Eg:

```
INSERT INTO all_items
VALUES (999)
```

```
ERROR:  null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (999, null).
```

I tried to use triggers in order for it to work but it didn't:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fill_NULL_attributes()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.name IS NULL THEN
    NEW.name := 'X'; -- fills empty attribute with some value
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql

CREATE TRIGGER all_items_insert_fix
    INSTEAD OF INSERT ON all_items
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE fill_NULL_attributes();
```

This trigger solution didn't work because **NEW** doesn't have the "name" attribute.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Where does `C1` come from? Please present a consistent case. And always disclose your version of Postgres. Would a column default for `name` be acceptable?

Comment: An `INSTEAD OF` trigger for a view needs to run an actual INSERT statement into the real table.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger function would be correct in a `BEFORE` trigger, since it modifies the row you are about to insert. But that is not correct in an `INSTEAD OF` trigger: there, you have to perform the `INSERT` into the base table yourself.